# drupal 7 default table to store form values

Tags: 7, hooks, database

I am new to drupal and creating a module consist of a form. Now I want to store values in database, please tell me what is the default table in drupal to store form values?
Like in WordPress we have wp_option table to save data. 
Is there any default table in drupal or I have to create new one?
What is the exact use of node table?

Comment: Where you got the idea there is any default table for form data? Each module provides it's own forms and it's own db tables. For example there is core node.module, but it's tables have nothing to do with anything else. Have you read docs and seen Examples project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Drupal variable system, please read the following article: https://www.drupal.org/node/1111260

You can create you own table, just use hook_schema for it: https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_schema/7

If you to get information from your users by form and store it, please check the module webform:  https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Node table used for storing main information about nodes (it's some type of content). Node can by "Article" or "News", etc. More you can read here: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/node

Answer (score 0):

The default table to store values in database is the variable table; you can use `variable_set()` to store values and `variable_get()` to get those values.

```
//Example:
variable_set('app_id', $form_submit['values']['app_id']);
variable_get('app_id');

function test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $app_id = $form_state['values']['app_id'];
  $app_secret = $form_state['values']['app_secret'];
  $app_code = base64_encode($app_id . ':' . $app_secret);

   if ($form_state['values']['app_id'] && $form_state['values']['app_secret']) {
     variable_set('app_id', $form_state['values']['app_id']);
     variable_set('app_secret', $form_state['values']['app_secret']);
     drupal_set_message(t('App Code data Saved app_id= ' . variable_get('app_id') . ' app_sec=' . variable_get('app_secret')));
  }
}
```